# Substantiv für »Aufteilung in einem Gitter«

Tags: translation, english-to-german, single-word-request

Gibt es ein Substantiv für *den Prozess des Aufteilens in einem Gitter?* Vgl. auf Englisch *Gridding*. (Kontext: Mathe)

Comment: Du könntest den Kontext noch etwas genauer beschreiben. Was Du suchst, könnte eventuell _Verfeinerung_ sein, aber um das zu beurteilen, müßte man den Zusammenhang genau kennen.

Answer (score 7):

Die Seite [linguee.de](http://www.linguee.de/englisch-deutsch/uebersetzung/gridding.html) liefert Übersetzungsbeispiele anhand "echter" Texte - und ist (jedenfalls für mich) der erste Google-Treffer für "gridding". Nach den Treffern dort zu urteilen, wird *gridding* oft mit *Rastern* übersetzt, bzw. mit Varianten von *Raster*, die im jeweiligen Kontext passen.

*Raster* ist in einem im weiteren Sinne mathematischen Kontext eine gültige Alternative zu *Gitter*, und *Rastern* könnte verstanden werden als "ein Raster anwenden", aber auch "auf ein Raster abbilden". Von daher scheinen mir die Vorschläge bei linguee durch aus valide zu sein.

Comment: _Raster_ ist sicher in dem hier angesprochenen Sinne nicht passend.

Comment: @MartinPeters Kannst du auch sagen warum?

Comment: Gitter ≠ Raster